# Communication between parent and nodes

Tags: java, message-queue

We have a `parent` that holds information about many `nodes`. Each node is separate VM instance, that performs different tasks. `parent` is like a dashboard for all the nodes.

The `parent` needs to:

- send some occasional configuration changes to some `node`
- monitor the heartbeat i.e. the health of the `node`
- get some statistic data from the `node`

I would like that `node` is unaware of the outside world as much as possible. Each `node` works as a web server, they can have big traffic sometimes.

How to communicate in the best way between the `parent` and the `node`?

I was thinking into using files for communication, so `parent` can set a file with a command on a `node` file-system, and then to have a dir watcher that reads for such files.

Or to have some event-bus/message-queue in the background, but they are using sockets, so a `node` may become un-responsive for `parent`s message in case of high-traffic. Or maybe I worry too much?

EDIT

Is there any event/message-bus that offers direct communication between channels, to save the time for broadcasting? In my example, the communication between is always between a `parent` and single `child`, there is no need to broadcast. So we could have some messaging like email ;)

EDIT #2 - about communication and traffic

There is one `parent` (or a cluster that represents one instance of a parent). Number of `childs` is not determined, it may be any; the goal is to have as much as possible, as long the system works fine. The communication is:

1. Commands (`parent` -> `child`)
   Low-frequent commands, usually initiated by admin (e.g. "restart", "upload", "reload config"). It goes directly to specific `child`.
2. Runtime stats (each `child` -> `parent`)
   Each `child` notifies the `parent` about its health (heartbeat) and some minor stats. This does not have to be a real-time communication, as long as the message is transferred under e.g. 10 seconds.
3. Runtime logs (each `child` -> `parent`)
   Important logs about the traffic and usage. This may be high-volume data as it is important to measure each node, if the computation gets over certain limit we need to be aware of that etc. Again, not real-time, but we need a promptly alert on high computation.

There is no much need of general broadcasting (since `child`s are not aware of other childs), this is more direct messaging.

Comment: how many nodes do you have? what kind of data you are sending from the parent node?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use [RMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation), since you can implement the methods you're needing to communicate between nodes, making the class you want to comunicate extends the `Remote` interface.

You'll have to use the `rmiregistry` at the beginning of the comunication, but then it won't be needed again if you have a "central" node to distribute the references/messages (like in a chat (server/clients) model).

**Update**: I'm not that advanced to answer your last question, but maybe this links can help you to find out if that's what you need:

1.- [Overview](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/overview.html)

2.- [How fast RMI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068958/how-fast-might-rmi-be)

Comment: How robust is RMI in every-day usage with many nodes? How light are the messages?

Comment: for example, I know the mean response time of JMS application increases is far lower than that of RMI application

Comment: Updated with some links @игор, hope the second one can clarify what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the simplest solution would be to send an http POST to the node to change configuration (especially if it already is a web-server). A heartbeat could just be HEAD request. A statistics gathering request might be a get.

You could use servlet security mechanisms to ensure that the configuration was only changed by the parent.

If you have performance issues, a solution like RMI or ZeroMQ, might be good, but it introduces extra complexity.

A good http client library like this one https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/ would get you a long way.