# Java - Using a static list from another class

Tags: java, singleton, static-variables

I have a class like this , where I am updating a static variable in a thread. And I need to access this variable from another class.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class VariableUpdater implements Runnable {
    static List < String > abc = new ArrayList < String > ();

    private static VariableUpdater instance = null;

    private VariableUpdater() {}

    public static synchronized VariableUpdater getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new VariableUpdater();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread th = new Thread( VariableUpdater.getInstance());
        th.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println();
            try {
                abc.add("aa");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                printContent();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

        }

    }

    public synchronized void printContent() {
        for (String string: abc) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
}
```

And this variable needs to be accessed from another class like this :

```
public class Accessor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        VariableUpdater.getInstance().printContent();
    }
}
```

The problem is, when running the Accessor class the list is empty.

Am I missing something here?

**UPDATE/Solution**

It turns out we can achieve this by using Hazelcast or some sort of messaging/caching utility. I will post a full solution soon.

Source: [How to share object between java applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244755/how-to-share-object-between-java-applications)

Comment: You have two `main` methods. Assuming you start the last one: when do you start your thread?

Comment: I run the VariableUpdater class first. The logic updates the variable in each one second. And the list needs to be accessed from the Accessor class.

Comment: You have to two JVM instances. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have two `main()` methods in two different classes. On running two `main()` methods there will be two instances of JVM and those do not share anything. So your list will always be empty.

Use one `main()` method to start threads.

```
public class Main{

    //shared state
    public static void main(String[] args){

        VariableUpdator variableUpdatorInstance = ...
        Accessor accessorInstance = ...


        variableUpdatorInstance.start();
        accessorInstance.start();


        //or in your case
        new Thread(new VariableUpdater()).start();
        Thread.sleep(9000); //runs eventually after 9 seconds
        Accessor.print(); 

    }    
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
class Thread1 extends Thread{

    static List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

}

class OtherClass{

    public void someMethod(){
        Thread1.list; //this is how you access static variable of one class in other
    }
}
```

Comment: that's not what i wanted. i need the VariableUpdater class running in background and the list needs to be accessed from another class which runs occasionally.

Comment: use `Thread.sleep(9000)` which will simulate the being run eventually. Check the updated answer.

Comment: this requires the same class to be ran... that's not what i wanted.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please elaborate with a proper example. You can't start two main methods and expect them to share state.

Answer (score 1):

From this code u can access the List in another class object

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

 public class VariableUpdater implements Runnable {
 static List < String > abc = new ArrayList < String > ();

private static VariableUpdater instance = null;

private VariableUpdater() {}

public static synchronized VariableUpdater getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new VariableUpdater();
    }
    return instance;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread th = new Thread(new VariableUpdater());
    th.start();
    Accessor.print();
}

@Override
public void run() {
   for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        System.out.println();
        try {
            abc.add("aa");
           // Thread.sleep(1000);
            //printContent();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

public synchronized void printContent() {
        System.out.println("List :: " + abc);
}
 }

class Accessor {
public static void print() {
    System.out.println("Accessor");
    VariableUpdater.getInstance().printContent();
  }
}
```

Comment: that's not what i wanted. i need the VariableUpdater class running in background and the list needs to be accessed from another class which runs occasionally.