# how should i navigate from one window that uses an application window to another frame in another application window?

Tags: java, swing

i am developing an application for which i have created different application windows. Now i'm in a confusion on how i can link one to another using a button, that is when i click a button, it has to navigate to the other application window. I have tried it with frames from same file, but that doesnt satisfy my need.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.SystemColor;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.swing.UIManager;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Start {

private JFrame frame;
private JTextField txtLogInTo;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Start window = new Start();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}


private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(SystemColor.inactiveCaption);
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("USER");
    btnNewButton.setBackground(SystemColor.activeCaption);
    btnNewButton.setBounds(152, 81, 132, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

    JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("BUS ADMIN");
    btnNewButton_1.setBackground(SystemColor.activeCaption);
    btnNewButton_1.setBounds(152, 131, 132, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_1);


    JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("SYSTEM ADMIN");
    btnNewButton_2.setBackground(SystemColor.activeCaption);
    btnNewButton_2.setBounds(152, 179, 132, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_2);

    txtLogInTo = new JTextField();
    txtLogInTo.setBounds(95, 27, 252, 36);
    txtLogInTo.setBackground(SystemColor.inactiveCaption);
    txtLogInTo.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    txtLogInTo.setFont(new Font("Tekton Pro Cond", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 20));
    txtLogInTo.setText("LOG IN TO ENTER THE SYSTEM");
    frame.getContentPane().add(txtLogInTo);
    txtLogInTo.setColumns(10);
     class handler implements ActionListener
        {
            //must implement method
            //This is triggered whenever the user clicks the login button
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                if(btnNewButton.isEnabled())
                {User u;

                }

                }//if
            }//method

        }//inner class

}
```

and this above program is where i have to navigate when i click a button from the below program

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.SystemColor;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class User {

private JFrame frame,frame2;
private JTextField txtWelcomeUser;
private JTextField txtEnterYourDetails;
private JTextField txtName;
private JTextField txtAge;
private JTextField txtPhoneNo;
private JTextField txtMailId;
private JTextField txtStart;
private JTextField txtDestination;
private JTextArea textArea_4;
private JTextArea textArea_5;
private JTextField txtEn;
   private ActionListener action;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                User window = new User();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}


public User() {
    initialize();
}


private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(0, 0, 750, 550);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);



    txtWelcomeUser = new JTextField();
    txtWelcomeUser.setBackground(SystemColor.inactiveCaption);
    txtWelcomeUser.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 26));
    txtWelcomeUser.setText("Welcome user");
    txtWelcomeUser.setBounds(176, 11, 173, 52);
    frame.getContentPane().add(txtWelcomeUser);
    txtWelcomeUser.setColumns(10);

    txtEnterYourDetails = new JTextField();
    txtEnterYourDetails.setBackground(SystemColor.activeCaption);
    txtEnterYourDetails.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    txtEnterYourDetails.setText("Enter your details");
    txtEnterYourDetails.setBounds(176, 74, 173, 36);
    frame.getContentPane().add(txtEnterYourDetails);
    txtEnterYourDetails.setColumns(10);

    txtName = new JTextField();
    txtName.setBackground(SystemColor.inactiveCaption);
    txtName.setText("Name");
    txtName.setBounds(93, 136, 86, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(txtName);
    txtName.setColumns(10);

    txtAge = new JTextField();
    txtAge.setBackground(SystemColor.inactiveCaption);
    txtAge.setText("Age");
    txtAge.setBounds(93, 167, 86, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(txtAge);
    txtAge.setColumns(10);

    txtPhoneNo = new JTextField();
    txtPhoneNo.setBackground(SystemColor.inactiveCaption);
    txtPhoneNo.setText("Phone No");
    txtPhoneNo.setBounds(93, 198, 86, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(txtPhoneNo);
    txtPhoneNo.setColumns(10);

    txtMailId = new JTextField();
    txtMailId.setBackground(SystemColor.inactiveCaption);
    txtMailId.setText("Mail id");
    txtMailId.setBounds(93, 229, 86, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(txtMailId);
    txtMailId.setColumns(10);

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setBounds(236, 134, 124, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textArea);

    JTextArea textArea_1 = new JTextArea();
    textArea_1.setBounds(236, 165, 124, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textArea_1);

    JTextArea textArea_2 = new JTextArea();
    textArea_2.setBounds(236, 196, 124, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textArea_2);

    JTextArea textArea_3 = new JTextArea();
    textArea_3.setBounds(236, 227, 124, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textArea_3);

    txtStart = new JTextField();
    txtStart.setBackground(SystemColor.inactiveCaption);
    txtStart.setText("Start ");
    txtStart.setBounds(93, 260, 86, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(txtStart);
    txtStart.setColumns(10);

    txtDestination = new JTextField();
    txtDestination.setBackground(SystemColor.inactiveCaption);
    txtDestination.setText("Destination");
    txtDestination.setBounds(93, 291, 86, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(txtDestination);
    txtDestination.setColumns(10);

    textArea_4 = new JTextArea();

    textArea_4.setBounds(236, 258, 124, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textArea_4);

    textArea_5 = new JTextArea();
    textArea_5.setBounds(236, 289, 124, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textArea_5);



    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
    panel.setBackground(SystemColor.inactiveCaption);
    panel.setBounds(433, 213, 124, 115);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

    txtEn = new JTextField();
    txtEn.setBackground(SystemColor.inactiveCaption);
    txtEn.setText("Enter Bus No");
    txtEn.setBounds(93, 322, 86, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(txtEn);
    txtEn.setColumns(10);

    JTextArea textArea_6 = new JTextArea();
    textArea_6.setBounds(236, 320, 124, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textArea_6);

    JButton btnBookTicket = new JButton("Book Ticket");
    btnBookTicket.setBackground(SystemColor.activeCaption);
    btnBookTicket.setBounds(176, 376, 116, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnBookTicket);

    JPopupMenu popupMenu_1 = new JPopupMenu();
    popupMenu_1.setBounds(327, 376, 200, 50);
    frame.getContentPane().add(popupMenu_1);



                    if(!textArea.isEnabled()||!textArea_2.isEnabled()||!textArea_3.isEnabled()||!textArea_3.isEnabled()||!textArea_4.isEnabled()||!textArea_5.isEnabled()||!textArea_6.isEnabled())
                {


                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have not entered a few details","UnSuccessful",
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                }
                if(btnBookTicket.isEnabled())
                {

                    btnBookTicket.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {



                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have booked successfully","Success",
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                                    JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();


                                    if (button == btnBookTicket)
                                    {
                                        frame2 = new JFrame("FRAME 2");
                                        frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);      
                                        frame2.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                                        JPanel contentPane2 = new JPanel();
                                        contentPane2.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                                        JButton btnBookTicket1 = new JButton("Cancel Ticket");
                                        btnBookTicket1.setBackground(SystemColor.activeCaption);

                                        btnBookTicket1.setBounds(0, 30, 35, 23);
                                        contentPane2.add(btnBookTicket1);
                                        frame2.getContentPane().add(contentPane2);
                                        frame2.setSize(600, 600);
                                        frame2.setVisible(true);
                                        frame.setVisible(false);


                                    }



                            btnBookTicket.addActionListener(action);



                       }
                 });


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe see this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1680898/2891664. Frankly, judging by your description though, it seems like you shouldn't be using separate programs. For example, maybe the login frame should be a `JDialog` which pops up when the program starts and then creates the `JFrame`. http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/2891664

Comment: @Radiodef, that JDialog and JFrame thing worked for me.. thank u

Comment: But the problem is that my application has to reuse a lot of code and i don't wanna specify them every time.

Comment: You could make a method that creates a `JDialog` and returns it, or create a class that extends `JDialog`. Then you can create a login dialog on-demand, any time you need to.